# using sql scripts in javascript

Tags: javascript, sql, database

can i use javascript to save an item to a database using sql script?

Answer (score 4):

Not directly, unless you are working with a [client-side database](http://webkit.org/blog/126/webkit-does-html5-client-side-database-storage/). However, you can hook JavaScript up with a server-side script (whichever backend you'd prefer) using [XMLHttpRequest](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-XMLHttpRequest-20090820/).

Answer (score 3):

You really don't want to do this. If you store SQL in your client-side javascript, you are exposing the details and structure of your database to an attacker. Creating an AJAX method to execute passed in javascript without creating a hole and attacker could use to perform SQL Injection attacks would be quite difficult.

Comment: As long as your server-side script does a thorough job of input sanitization, this isn't a bad idea. Assuming that you don't pass a string of raw SQL as a variable...that would be bad.

Answer (score 1):

As in Javascript on the browser? No, you can't.

Hypothetically you could use AJAX techniques to push SQL commands through a server layer and thence to the database but you really, *really* wouldn't want to since that would be an unholy mother of all security risks.

Answer (score 0):

no, you'd have to use some serverside processing language , such as php, asp....

Comment: can i pass a javascript value to a php variable? for example i will get the value of a textarea through javascript then copy it to a php variable.

Comment: yes, you can pass JS data as a querystring param or in a form input when you make a request

Comment: can you give me an example. i'm sorry i'm such a noob.

Comment: if you are a noobie, i suggest you use the jquery javascript library. It will ease your learning curve a lot. Then you could do something like:

$.post("test.cgi",
{ name: "John", time: "2pm" },
function(data){
alert("Data saved: " + data);
}
);

Here is a good starting point: http://www.sitepoint.com/article/ajax-jquery/